# Get link to (first) comment if there are comments today in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, foreach, comments

I have this function and a link to a post:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $id) {
  $post = &get_post( $id->ID );
  setup_postdata($post);

  <li><a <?php href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

</li>
  <?php
} ?>
```

What I want to do is this: if there is a comment posted **today**, than show me the link to the first comment that has been posted. So for example: if there are 4 comments made today, I want the link to the first comment instead of the permalink just like now.

I tried using this:
    `<a <?php href="<?php the_permalink(get_comments->$post_id) ?>">postname</a>` and variations of this like `comment_post_ID`, but I could not get it to work. What am I doing wrong and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confused about objects and functions (either that or you copy/pasted in wrong). When you tried to do get_comments->$post_id, that wouldn't work because get_comments is not an object, [get_comments is a function that accepts parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments). Check out what I did below as it may help you:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $id) {
  $post = &get_post( $id->ID );
  setup_postdata($post);

  $args = array('post_id' => $id->ID, 'number' => 1);
  $lastComment = get_comments($args);

  if (!empty($lastComment[0]) and $lastComment[0]->comment_date > date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')){
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_comment_link($lastComment[0]).'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
  }
?>
```

get_comments() will take a bunch of arguements, in the above I passed it the postID and the count of 1, so that it only pulls the last comment. It will still pull comments not made today though so the if condition I added in should only echo it if the comment was posted after midnight on today.

Comment: Check it again, I made an edit. I don't know 100% it will work, it was meant more to get you on the right track. For syntax errors you can generally look for the line number to try and fix those. It was the <li> tag within the <?php breaking it I think.

Comment: If I test it, it gives me `Cannot use string offset as an array in `. Am wondering too what the solution might be. Good question man.

Comment: I just ran it local and there were two things wrong. 1) I was using 'count' => 1 instead of 'number' => 1. 'count' will tell it to return just a count of the number of comments. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments 2) I had been anticipating an array to be returned when it was an object.

Comment: But this just gets me the `most recent comment`, instead of the `most recent comment per post`. Can you fix that, please? That's the question actually...

Comment: If you look at the $args array, it does have the post_id parameter in there. So as long as $id->ID is changing (and is the correct post id) it should only pull in the last comment per post.

Comment: Brother, I have pasted your code now and now, it is not generating a link. It's just the title in plain text....

Comment: Can  you help me out, please?

Comment: Does changing the "the_title()" to "get_the_title($id->ID)" work? I think the_title() will try and print directly out and get_the_title() will return the title as a string. If it doesn't, try viewing the source of the page and looking for the <a> tag to see if something isn't formatted right with that output.

Comment: It makes a link now if I do that, but still gets the most recent comment of a post... But that's for just one post, not all posts. So beneath every list item, I see a link to the sitewide most recently commented post. I want it for all posts... Can you help me please?

Comment: What query or function gets the $results array? Can you post that and possibly what is shown if you print_r($results) before the foreach loop?